# Ошибка в xcode при переходе в симулятор

Tags: xcode

я новичек в xcode.

Пишу приложение по гайдам в интернете. При запуске симулятора и выбора определенного иконки в приложении появляется ошибка : Thread 1: "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40504ECB-98BA-4035-AFB5-8BE71221ED43/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6B2C8168-2EE9-4873-8EAE-9437880A7627/vkbilder.app> (loaded)' with name 'HeaderView'"

код из файла HeaderView

```
    import UIKit
    
    class HeaderView: UIView {
    
        static func instantiate() -> HeaderView {
            let view: HeaderView = initFromNib()
            return view 
        }
        
    }
    
    extension UIView {
        class func initFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
            
            return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! T
        }
    }
```

Как можно решить данную проблему? заранее извиняюсь за неправильную формулировку/